# Visualize 3D objects from fusion table in google earth api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth

I want to visualize a `Google Fusion Table` data, with Google Earth API.

For Google Map, it is possible for simple 2d geometry:

```
  ##javascript    
  var map = new google.maps.Map(..)

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    ...
  });
```

How to visualize 3d-polygon's geometry for Google Earth API?

Answer (score 0):

It it pity, but there is impossible to render complex 3d polygins directly from google Fusion Table..